# How was/Was Kalam-sat Recovered from the Ocean?

Tags: landing, reentry, cubesat

[image: Kalam-SAT Beta-1]

I was reading this article about [Kalam-SAT](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/science/nasa-launches-worlds-lightest-satellite-designed-by-18-year-old-tamil-nadu-student/smallest-3d-printed-satellite/slideshow/59283141.cms) and it states that:

> "Kalamsat fell into the sea. It will be recovered and NASA will be sending it back to us for decoding the data," [Srimathy Kesan, mission director] said.

For those unfamiliar, here's the [wikipedia entry on the satellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalam_SAT).

**My question is, how did this thing survive re-entry, then survive impact with the ocean, and then transmit its location with a strong enough signal to be found and recovered?** If it was not an incorrectly stated tid-bit, does anyone have a more complete article, perhaps from a better source, that includes results of the mission?

Comment: It sounds more like PR Sat because it was never in orbit.

Comment: @OrganicMarble ahh, that would cover a few points of the question I suppose; still, the recovery of it is a tad bit perplexing. How would you find a quarter in an ocean if it wasn't meant to transmit data back over long distances in the first place?

Comment: Agreed. My superficial googling showed no evidence of it actually being recovered.

Comment: To be fair, it seems that future versions are planned to go to orbit, but all the press releases trumpeting "Smallest satellite EVAR!!111!!" got on my nerves.

Comment: @OrganicMarble where'd you find the info on future launches? I'm honestly just curious about the ability of this little thing to be recovered from a sub-orbital/orbital trajectory. Even throwing it out of a plane over the ocean and finding it again seems unlikely. I've yet to find anything but the praise articles, honestly. No documentation or anything, is there a NASA link for this?

Comment: That's why I didn't write up an answer, I took this "In its **first** deployment, KalamSat would be a technology demonstrator satellite" to mean it would fly again, but it doesnt explicitly say that. (from the wikipedia article)

Comment: @OrganicMarble I cannot find mentions of a NASA-based article saying that this was ever a payload (using basic searches). I'd expect `"kalamsat" inurl:nasa.gov` would have something somewhere, but 0 results in quotes and only a handful of results with additional spellings. Did I just stumble upon fake news?

Comment: This GSFC link talks about the launch https://sites.wff.nasa.gov/code810/news/story212%20RockOn%202017.html and this linked page has more info if you click the "2017 data and media" tab. https://spacegrant.colorado.edu/rockon-2017-registration  Sounds like it was all run by Colorado Space Grant Consortium, NASA just provided and launched the vehicle. Strictly an educational thing - although a pretty cool one.

Comment: Technology demonstrator doesn't imply re-flying. It may demonstrate a successful use of given technology which then can be used by others if they decide they want it, or it may demonstrate unsuccessful use of technology, which depending on the situation may mean a retry or mothballing the project forever. Lots of university cubesats are technology demonstrators where students test one idea or another, resulting in a good final grade and no other consequence.

Comment: Doesn't "first" imply at least a "second"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Most likely, providing the demonstration is successful. With bad failures funds tend to dry up.

Comment: @OrganicMarble where did you find that Kalamsat was a part of the CSGC?

Comment: The GSFC launch page for the day they claim the Kalamsat flew shows that it was run by those universities.  I don't see anything explicit about Kalamsat though.

Comment: @OrganicMarble oh, right, launch dates don't usually coincide-- especially when you include the location; good call there.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I'm not sure I believe it was recovered either, but https://www.indiatoday.in/magazine/nation/story/20171225-rifath-shaarook-and-team-christened-kalamsat-satellite-made-entirely-with-reinforced-carbon-fibre-polymer-1107581-2017-12-15 says it was recovered in November 2017 ("last month" in a December article)

Comment: NASA says that payload recovery was required for this mission. https://spacegrant.colorado.edu/images/RockOn/2017/Media/RockOn%202017%20MOD%20Final.pdf

Comment: That document mentions a recovery plan document that I can't find online.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Personally, I think it *was* recovered, because NASA failing to recover something they promised to recover I would think would be newsworthy.

Comment: @called2voyage I never found the article stating that NASA promised to recover them, nice addition there for sure.

Comment: It looks like this microsat did no orbit at all, only a ballistic trajectory. It was never released but always inside a cover with the necessary heat shield and parachute as well as protection against salt water. I would say there was no independent satellite at all. Are there any facts prooving I am wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This article in ForbesIndia](http://www.forbesindia.com/article/innovation-nation/for-these-wonder-kids-the-sky-is-not-the-limit/50043/1)  has what appears to be an adapted infographic showing the sounding rocket itself descending from apogee, deploying a parachute, and being recovered by the US Navy.  [The Wallops press release on the launch](https://www.nasa.gov/Wallops/2017/feature/nasa-wallops-successful-launch-rocks-with-student-experiments), which in NASA tradition was not trivial to search for, agrees:

> The experiments, launch on a 36-foot long Terrier-Improved Orion sounding rocket, flew to an altitude of 72 miles and landed, via parachute, in the Atlantic Ocean.  The payload has been recovered and the students are expected to receive their experiments this afternoon to begin their data analysis.

My guess is the satellite was contained, and recovered, as part of a monolithic payload.

[image: Infographic showing "Kalmsat's Journey" including parachute and ocean recovery]

A couple thoughts, since I found the process of getting this answer interesting:

- Bing lets you apply a date range to the searches, making it easy to filter out the initial press blitz.  This is the only time I have ever found Bing legitimately useful.
- [The blog post "From Gulabjamun to the Stars"](https://ruchiraaa.wordpress.com/2018/06/21/from-gulabjamun-to-the-stars/) appears to have post-launch pictures of the satellite (or a simulacrum?)  At least [one other blogger](https://spaceflight2017.wordpress.com/2018/01/01/a-dream-turned-into-reality-having-kalamsat-at-home/) also claims to have seen Kalamsat post-return.

Though not images from that particular mission (and maybe not even of the same rocket type; I'm having trouble visually IDing sounding rocket pieces) I've found [a LinkedIn post with pictures of a Wallops sounding rocket payload in the water and on a recovery boat](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140630142535-119251343-sounding-rocket-water-recovery).

Comment: The unprotected electronics of this satellite would not survive exposure to salt water very long. Especially if there is some charge left in the batteries.

Comment: @Uwe Concur.  I don't think the tiny satellite was exposed on its own, but I can't find a source discussing those kind of specifics at this time.

Comment: That sound you hear is Edward Tufte's head exploding.  Look how the distance from the recovery point to Wallops is 4 times the distance from Wallops to Chennai, India.  "Nice" graphic, Forbes.

Comment: For what it's worth, Google also lets you apply a date range to searches.

Comment: Didn't notice you included the NASA Wallops link. I eventually stumbled across it too.

Comment: @called2voyage you might've seen one of the edits where I forgot to put the actual link in.  How do you do Google date range searches?  I tried to figure it out, and didn't see it in the advanced search options, but didn't bother Googling how...

Comment: It's tools/select "any time" / set custom date range.

Comment: Ahhh! This would make sense if it was part of a bigger payload,was basically just a scientific instrument on-board, had a parachute attached to the bigger payload, didn't go into a full-on orbit and had some sort of protection against the salt water/elements. Still an awesome experience for those folks, even if it was misconstrued a little bit in media, but what isn't to be honest. Thanks for finding the actual source on it.

Comment: I found some Wallops payload-in-water and payload-on-boat images that may be representative.